# React save the onChange value and set it to another object if the user doesn't type anything within one second

Tags: reactjs

So, I'm trying to do something for my component, because I don't want for it to be rendered many times on each input, but rather, when 1 second is passed without the user typing something, after that to set it, but I'm facing some problems and what I've build don't work, it resets the state and so, Idk.

Here is the component:

```
import { Item } from '../..';
import { WorkItemValidation } from '../../../../../utils/Validation';
import { Date, Input } from '../../../Shared';
import { Editor } from '../../..';
import { Items } from '../Components';
import { Container, Liner, Linerier } from './Components'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Employment as Work } from '../../../../../utils/operations/Resume';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const Employment: any = (props: any) => {
    const [call, setCall] = useState(false);
    const [editors, setEditors] = useState({});
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState("");

    const handleDescription = (e: any, index: number) => {
        setCurrentIndex(index);
        setEditors( { ...editors, [index]: e } )
        setTimeout(() => setCall(true), 1000)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            if (call === true) {
                Work.Description(props, currentIndex, editors[currentIndex])
                setCurrentIndex("")
                setCall(false)
            }
        }, 1000)
    }, [])


    return (
        <Container>
            <Items>
                {
                    props.resume.employmentHistory.positions.map(
                        (position: any, index: number) => {

                            return (
                                                     <Editor
                                            label="Description"
                                            value={position.description && position.description || ''}
                                            
                                            onChange={(e) => handleDescription(e, index)}
                                        />
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
            </Items>
        </Container >
    )
}

export default Employment;
```

So to handle when user types, after 1 second if he didn't put anything to change the state with the function Work.Description.

Answer (score 0):

This is called debouncing a function and you may do it like:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState();
  const timeoutRef = React.useRef();
  
  const debounce = (func, args, delay) => {
    if (timeoutRef.current) {
      // canceling the previous timeout so the callback won't fire if
      // the user presses another key before 1 second
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    }
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      // calling func here will debounce it
      func(args);
    }, delay)
  }
  
  const handleChange = (inputValue) => {
    setValue(inputValue);
  }

  console.log("App rendered");

  return (
   <React.Fragment>
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={(e) => debounce(handleChange, e.target.value, 1000)}
    />
    <p>Debounced value: {value}</p>
   </React.Fragment>
  )
}


ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a full example with my scenario?

Comment: because i do have many components that I render, this one I think doesn't wor'k

Comment: I have updated the answer with a working example. @nevoni3008

Comment: I mean working example with my case, I do have multiple editors (inputs) so is not the same.

Comment: Also i need this without useReff, because I do a public state with all the other items in my project.

Comment: I can't make a working example from your code because there are quite a few imported components plus I don't have an understanding of your app logic. I have to use a ref because keeping timeout id in state beats the purpose of debouncing coz change in state will rerender the component. However what you can do is: move the debouncing code down into the Editor component and only call `onChange()` after debouncing. TBH I don't understand "public state" and how ref is a problem here...